# How to Format Page In Css

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this code

```css
.form-horizontal {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

%transition {
  transition: background .35s ease;
}


/*Base*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eecda3 0%, #ef629f 100%);
}


/*Typography*/

html {
  font: 16px Verdana;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

li {
  font-size: 1em;
}


/*Layout*/


/*Dropdown*/

.dropdown {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 14.5em;
  border: .1em solid #c0cdd1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  @extend %transition;
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    background: #ecf0f1;
  }
  &:active {
    background: #fbfcfc;
  }
}

.da {
  float: right
}


/*List*/

ul {
  display: none;
  border-top: .1em solid #c0cdd1;
}

li {
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  @extend %transition;
  &:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: .1em dashed #dde4e6;
  }
  &:last-child {
    color: #ad0000;
  }
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    background: #ecf0f1;
  }
  &:active {
    background: #fbfcfc;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form-horizontal">

  <center>
    <h4>Start Tracking A Product </h4>
  </center>
  <center>
    <p>* = required</p>
  </center>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We Will Notify This Email When The Target Price Is Reached.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Target Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Ex: 250">
  </div>

  <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">     Start Track    </button></center>
</form>
```

You can also run it on codepen
https://codepen.io/sochum/pen/mdLKqPP

And I would like to put the form inside a white block that goes vertically. I want the background color to only be on the parts outside of the white block.

How would I put the form inside a div like that?

Example Of What I Am trying to do
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please [edit] your question to add a [mre] (from the code in the pen) - questions here should be self-sufficient just in the case the link is no longer reachable and leaves the question incomplete (thus, unable to be answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you could simply enhance your `.form-horizontal` class to be like this:

```
.form-horizontal {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white; /* new */
  padding: 2em;            /* new */
  height: 100%;            /* new */
}
```

**See demo code below**

```css
.form-horizontal {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100%;
}

%transition {
  transition: background .35s ease;
}


/*Base*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eecda3 0%, #ef629f 100%);
}


/*Typography*/

html {
  font: 16px Verdana;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

li {
  font-size: 1em;
}


/*Layout*/


/*Dropdown*/

.dropdown {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 14.5em;
  border: .1em solid #c0cdd1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  @extend %transition;
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    background: #ecf0f1;
  }
  &:active {
    background: #fbfcfc;
  }
}

.da {
  float: right
}


/*List*/

ul {
  display: none;
  border-top: .1em solid #c0cdd1;
}

li {
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  @extend %transition;
  &:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: .1em dashed #dde4e6;
  }
  &:last-child {
    color: #ad0000;
  }
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    background: #ecf0f1;
  }
  &:active {
    background: #fbfcfc;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form-horizontal">

  <center>
    <h4>Start Tracking A Product </h4>
  </center>
  <center>
    <p>* = required</p>
  </center>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We Will Notify This Email When The Target Price Is Reached.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Target Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Ex: 250">
  </div>

  <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">     Start Track    </button></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a div then put the form inside that div then give background color to the div (whatever you want)

Comment: no need to place the form into a new `div` - you can style the `<form>` tag as well

Comment: but it will be easier to play with design I think

Comment: Not really, no... You are just adding another div with no additional use other than to add a background (which you can do w/o)

Comment: in my opinion when we go with div we have a lot of space to play around

Comment: Not necessarily, like I said, you are just creating more tags with no additional use in this case - the question, remember, is not asking about having "space to play around"; it's a very specific question - besides StackOverflow is a Questions and Answers site (not an opinion site) - Please read [answer]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).